# iOS iPhone - is there a 2013 equivalent of Three20, a framework for building apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I know that TTT(Three20)framework provides quite a lot of customization of default iOS elements, however, it appears that the framework has not been updated in over a year, and a lot of tutorials on the framework I see are dated 2011 or so.

Is there some newer, better framework that industry apps are using? Or is Three20 still relevant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you correctly stated, Three20 is no longer used (it was too heavy, and you never got to use it entirely anyways). 
Nowadays, I think people tend to follow a "componentization" (sorry for the lingo) approach, which means you just put in your project stuff that you know you'll be using that can be easily added/removed. This way, if you change your mind about using a certain component, you can discard it at any time and replace it with another one almost in a couple of minutes.

To accomplish this, I'd have a look to [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) and [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/).

The first one to browse across all sorts of visual and non-visual components, 3rd party libraries and so on. The second one to actually import those into your project with minimal hassle.

This way your project will only include classes that will be used, and won't be that difficult to set up.

If you're looking for a magic toolbox that does it all, I'm afraid it doesn't exist (and I don't think it ever did).